# Are instance variables passed by reference in Java?

Tags: java, variables, reference, pass-by-reference

Now I know that Java is purely passed-by-value, but are instance variables passed by reference?

Here's what I mean (and I know this code is terrible, but it's pseudo-code:

```
//Instance variables
private Object[] array = new Object[10];
array[4] = new Object[5];

//Private method
private Object ar(int x)
{
     return array[x];
}

//Inside Main or some other method
ar(4)[0] = "Foo";
```

Now, would the first slot on the array in `array[4]` be changed to "Foo" because `array` is an instance variable?

### To Clarify:

I know that ***EVERYTHING*** is passed by value. But we are talking about calling things contained in instance variables, please focus on that. Thanks.

Comment: And before anyone comments saying something like `ar(4)[0]` doesn't work, well you're wrong. It does. I just needed to say that to get in before the hecklers. :)

Comment: `private array[4] = new Object[5];` doesn't look like valid java code.

Comment: http://blog.tmorris.net/java-is-pass-by-value/

Comment: @armandino yeah I am assuming he meant `array[4] = new Object[5];`

Comment: @armandino Yep, I realized I forgot to specify that those were instance variable, and I just threw `private` on both without thinking. Thanks!

Comment: *"And before anyone comments saying something..."* Why would anyone say that? No need to be paranoid. If someone did, the rest of us would slap 'em down...

Comment: I felt I needed to clarify. All too often have I posted a question, answer, or comment, and someone with little experience in the language has chimed in about how my code or idea is wrong. inb4. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the first slot in `array[4]` will be changed to `"Foo"`

In Java, everything is passed by value.  When passing objects, the reference to the object is passed by value. For your example, the object contained in `array[4]` is returned from the `ar` method.

Comment: Clarification to poster: *variables* are never passed. Only the value (see answer) that they contain.

Comment: +1, but I would say "the *object contained* in `array[4]` is returned" as there really is no "reference" outside of the implementation details. The key is to understand that an object-is-itself and no copy/clone/duplicate is done -- the rest are purely details.

Comment: +1...you are right that is a little more clear.  I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 4):

*Variables* are never passed. Only the values that they contain. That is: *it makes no difference if it is an instance variable or otherwise* (at least for sake of arguing "what is passed").

Remember that an object is-what-it-is and **there is no implicit copy/clone/duplicate of objects** -- this includes array objects -- themselves (consider primitives to be self-representing immutable entities).

Happy coding.

---

**Update:** I found this link and I like it. [Call by object](http://effbot.org/zone/call-by-object.htm). This term is attributed to Liskov.

> > But nevermind, the only thing you need to know is that <del>Python’s</del> Java's model is neither “call by value” nor “call by reference” (because any attempt to <del>use</del> [think in] those terms [is thinking in those terms]...) The most accurate description is CLU’s **“call by object”** or **“call by sharing“**. Or, if you prefer, **“call by object reference“.**

This sums the differences:

> > "IN PARTICULAR IT IS NOT CALL BY VALUE because mutations
> >         of arguments performed by the called routine will be visible to
> >         the caller. And IT IS NOT CALL BY REFERENCE because access
> >         is not given to the variables of the caller, but merely to certain
> >         objects."

Only in Java the "call-by-sharing" is implemented with "passing the value of the reference" -- *an implementation detail that doesn't need to be considered to describe calling semantics, objects, or object-identity*.

Answer (score 1):

From the authors of Java: "There is exactly one parameter passing mode in Java - pass by value - and that helps keep things simple." The Java Programming Language, 2nd ed. by Ken Arnold and James Gosling, section 2.6.1, page 40, 3rd paragraph.

Comment: that is meaningless, without knowing what `value` he's talking about. otherwise, all languages are pass by value. the question is what kind of value.

Comment: The problem is, he says he knows it's pass by value, but then goes on to ask if it's not in a certain case. I actually think the real issue is that he doesn't understand that arrays are objects, not primatives.

Comment: @irreputable Not all languages are [strictly] pass-by-value ;-) call-by-name and call-by-reference are not call/pass-by-value. VB without "ByVal" is purely call-by-reference AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

Java Lang Spec: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#4.1

§4.1 There are ... two kinds of data **values** that can be ... passed as arguments...: primitive values (§4.2) and **reference values**

§4.3 The reference values (often just **references**) are **pointers** to these objects

So Java is pass by "value", or "reference value", or "reference", or "pointer". (ignoring primitives)

All 4 versions are sanctioned by the language spec.

Now can we please stop this word game. We all know what is passed, isn't that enough? What about we call it pass by rose?

Comment: I'm not found of this parlance, but it doesn't deserve a -1, esp. when backed with a link so ... +1 :) It is, however, quite common to use "pass-by-reference" (and endorsed by Wikipedia, after a number of years) to mean "pass-by-value-of-reference" (I prefer the "pbvr" name for clarity).

Comment: @pst pass by reference gives the indication that you can change the reference in the called method and it will be changed in scope of the caller, which will not happen. That's the difference between the two. (And yes, it can be very confusing!)

Comment: @pst pass by reference and pass reference by value are two very different things.

Comment: *"So Java is pass by "reference value", or "reference", or "pointer". (ignoring primitives)"* That just confuses the issue. Java does not have pass-by-reference. Ever. At all. And you don't have to ignore primitives. Everything is passed by value. Primitives are passed by value, and object references are passed by value. It's so simple people try to make it complicated.

Comment: @glowcoder "pass-by-VALUE-of-reference" (pbvr) does that without convoluting the issue with "real" pass/call-by-reference semantics such as those found in C++ with "references" or in C# with `ref/out` where the actual *input variable can be reassigned*.

Comment: @TofuBeer I agree. See previous comment.

Comment: confusion arises when you try to describe the issue with a single word. tell "java is pass by value" to a c++ guy, and you think you are not confusing him?

Comment: @irreputable So? Java is not C++ or Haskell. Learn the language. Python'ers would very happily say "pass-by-reference" (but I stick with my "pbvr" term -- ideally I would just like to say "pass-by-object" :-)

Comment: @pst I learned it as "Java is pass by value, even for references". I think it's clear, even for C++ guys. Beyond that, we're just arguing semantics. Also, @irreputable, I loved your subtle Shakespeare reference :)

Comment: I personally don't care about the name. this word game has become more painful than passing a kidney stone.

Comment: Barbara Liskov invented the term *pass-by-sharing* (or *pass-by-object-sharing*) decades ago, to avoid precisely this confusion. I don't understand why it doesn't get used more widely. Just imagine how many millions of dollars were wasted by programmers explainig why Java is pass-by-value instead of just working on whatever they were supposed to work on.

Comment: @irreputable There are at least three possible things: pass by reference, pass by value, pass reference by value.  All three have different meanings.  Words are important... using the right ones is really important.

Comment: @TofuBeer Words are too important. people fight for the authority of words, usually to obfuscate the truth. In IT there are too many ill-defined words, and people make a living on bullshitting. In this world as it is, we should demote words, and promote meaning.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that code will set `array[4][0]` to "Foo". The fact that `array` is an instance variable is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I sort of answered my own question by running a pretty simple test, but some of the answers that have already been left helped clarify things a lot. I know something like 14 programming languages, so what language does what sometimes gets a little fuzzy.

```
public class ArrayPassTest {

    private Object[] array;

    public ArrayPassTest()
    {
        array = new Object[10];
        array[4] = new Object[10];
    }

    public Object[] ar(int x)
    {
        return (Object[])array[x];
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayPassTest apt = new ArrayPassTest();

        apt.ar(4)[0] = "Foo";

        System.out.println(apt.ar(4)[0]);
        System.out.println(apt.ar(4)[5]);

    }

}
```

outputs:

```
Foo
null
```

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

> I know that EVERYTHING is passed by
>   value. But we are talking about
>   calling things contained in instance
>   variables, please focus on that.
>   Thanks.

EVERYTHING includes 'things contained in instance variables'.

Surely that is obvious?

Answer (score -1):

the best way to think about it is that addresses of variables are being passed around unless it is a primitive. (with arrays being treated as non-primitive).  this would lead you to the answer you got from running your test program and also explain why.

(the terms "by-reference", "by-value", "instance" are ambiguous and confusing in this context.)

Comment: "Instance" is correct, unambiguous terminology. That's the name of the type of variable...